# Open source Tool to find unreachable/unused c# code

Tags: c#

is there any Open source static code analysis tool that can help to find unreachable /unused code in C# programs?

Comment: Er, Visual Studio gives warnings about unreachable or unused code ...

Comment: Only unused segments of functions, and that's handled by the compiler, not VS. I have a feeling the OP is talking about completely unused/uncalled functions, which aren't handled by the compiler.

Comment: @ApoY2k unreachable yes. Say you declare a method but never call it, that is not supported AFAIK.

Comment: Visual Studio produces warnings on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FxCop, which is built into higher editions of Visual Studio, will warn of unused private or internal members.  Right-click your project and choose Run Code Analysis.  In conjunction with "unreachable code segments" being identified by the compiler as others have noted, this should catch the remaining unused code.

(Note FxCop will *not* warn of unused public or protected members, because these could be part of an API intended for use by external callers.  Also, FxCop is not available in all editions of Visual Studio though older versions are available for download.)

Comment: FxCop is available seperately from VS though for free as far as I'm aware (I know it's available seperately, it's the free part I'm not sure about).

Comment: Yes, separate and free.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can suggest is a code coverage tool used on the main executable instead of a test assembly, then put the application through it's paces... A static analysis of code would be NP hard to do in some more esoteric cases.

Comment: It's much worse than NP-HARD. An exact static analysis of code coverage is practically *by definition* the Halting Problem. Clearly the question "does this line of code ever execute" is equivalent to "does this program ever halt?" (Just replace every halt in the program with an infinite loop, and the line in question with a halt, and then run your halting detector.)  The Halting Problem is certainly not NP-HARD; it's undeciable.

Comment: @Eric: I stopped just short of mentioning The Halting Problem, because while it sounded right to me, I wasn't quite sure it was applicable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Although not an open source tool you can use [R#](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (Resharper). it's a visual studio add-in that can show you unreachable code and can remove it automatically (using system clean-up).

Comment: It's **not** open source though, is it?

Comment: Is it at least free (of charge) or do you have to buy it?

Comment: It's not free but you can use their beta version for free (at least for now)- nightly builds are available at: http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code coverage tool, that is available in Visual Studio 2005/2008 Team Suite.

Answer (score -1):

The tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) can help find unused code in a .NET code base. However this tool is not Open Source. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developer of this tool.*

NDepend proposes to write [Code Rule over LINQ Query (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). Around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed, 3 of them being dedicated to *unused/dead code* detection:

- [Potentially dead Types](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Types.html) (hence detect unused class, struct, interface, delegate...)
- [Potentially dead Methods](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Methods.html) (hence detect unused method, ctor, property getter/setter...)
- [Potentially dead Fields](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Potentially_dead_Fields.html)

NDepend is integrated in Visual Studio, thus these rules can be [checked/browsed/edited right inside the IDE](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx). The tool can also be integrated into your CI process and it can build [reports](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx) that will show rules violated and culprit code elements.

If you click these 3 links above toward the source code of these rules, you'll see that the ones concerning types and methods are a bit complex. This is because they detect not only unused types and methods, but also types and methods used *only* by unused dead types and methods (recursive).

This is *static analysis*, hence the prefix *Potentially* in the rule names. If a code element is used *only* through reflection, these rules might consider it as unused which is not the case.

In addition to using these 3 rules, I'd advise measuring code coverage by tests and striving for having full coverage. Often, you'll see that code that cannot be covered by tests, is actually *unused/dead* code that can be safely discarded. This is especially useful in complex algorithms where it is not clear if a branch of code is reachable or not.